# No grub screen when i start my system

Tags: linux, windows, grub, grub2-mkconfig

no grub screen after installing ubuntu 18.04 it takes me straight to linux (i am a new person)[image]

Comment: Are you expecting a Windows install too? Doesn't look like one is detected.